# Could not fetch password hash from MySQL

Tags: php, passwords, verify

i've got a problem with password verify.
I'm trying to fetch an hash from my password column and then verify with the password from form. I'm not sure why it doesn't work:

```
        $pass = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT password FROM male_users WHERE email=$email");
        $hash = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pass);
        if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
            echo('Hello');
        } else  {
            echo('Email or Password not mach');
        }
```

It turns back an error: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given but i found on stack that people succesfully uses that. What am i doing wrong? Thnx in advance! 
best regards

Comment: Learn how to use quotes.

Comment: Do you really have separate database tables for users based on their gender?

Comment: `where email = '$email'`

Comment: try like this  WHERE email='".$email."');

Comment: Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, and `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returns an array not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this  and your mysqli_fetch_assoc return array so use $hash['password']  insted of $hash and finally use single quotes in where condition .

```
 $pass = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT password FROM male_users WHERE email='$email'");
    $hash = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pass);
    if (password_verify($password, $hash['password'])) {
        echo('Hello');
    } else  {
        echo('Email or Password not mach');
    }
```